# Can a gerund be modified by an adjective?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, gerund-phrases, diagramming, deverbal-nouns

Is the sentence below grammatically correct?

> Good writing requires hard work.

Or should it read:

> Writing well requires hard work.

Can a gerund be modified by an adjective or must it be modified necessarily by an adverb?

If it can be modified by an adjective, when you diagram it, would the *good* come off of the word *writing* on the stilt, or would it go below the regular baseline?

Answer (score 6):

Don't tell me.
Somebody has taught you that a noun formed from a verb by adding *-ing* is a gerund.
Indeed, that's what the "gerund" tag above says:

- **Gerund**: A noun formed from a verb by the addition of *-ing*.

Unfortunately, this is not true. A gerund is a **verb**, not a noun. And it behaves like a verb.
There **are** nouns formed from verbs with *-ing* [-- as well as other things --](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html) but they are not gerunds.
There are ways to check.

For instance, nouns can take articles and adjectives, while gerunds can take direct objects.
*The writing in this book is atrocious. There's good writing and there's bad writing.* (noun)
**The writing the novel exhausted her.* **Good writing a novel is what you want.* (gerund)

In the case of the first sentence, that's the noun *writing*, which can take an adjective.
In the case of the second, that's the gerund *writing*, which can take an adverb.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second set of examples:  "The writing the novel exhausted her."  or "Good writing a novel is what you want." They seem fragmented?     I was taught the definition:  "A gerund is a present participle verb form used as a noun."  Isn't "writing" functioning as a noun in my example sentence?  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: There's an asterisk before ungrammatical sentences. Those are ungrammatical sentences. The definition you learned is wrong. The gerund is not used as a noun; the clause of which it is the main verb functions as a noun phrase, but the gerund itself functions as a tenseless verb form, not a noun. Check the link for more details.

Comment: Ok, I checked out the link and am pondering these things. So, a present participle verb can function as a noun but not be a gerund? Is it considered a present participle verbal in this case?  A test is---if it can take an adjective, it is NOT a gerund. Is this correct?  Can you give me an example of a gerund taking an adverb? Must a gerund be a part of a phrase and have a direct object?  I am trying hard to get a grip on this....thank you.

Comment: No, no. You misunderstand me. The **gerund clause** functions as a noun phrase, usually as subject or object of a predicate. But the **gerund** itself is the verb of the gerund clause, and is not a noun itself. If it were a noun, it could take articles; but since it's a verb, it can take direct objects. Grammar is about constituents, like clauses and phrases, rather than about words.

Comment: Since gerund clauses are a type of complement, perhaps [this handout on English complement types](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complementtypes.pdf) will be helpful.

Comment: @Elizabeth: John Lawler's ungrammatical sentences could be made grammatical by simply omitting the words "The" and "Good." That is, "Writing the novel exhausted her," and "Writing a novel is what you want [to do]."

Comment: Ok...thank you for hanging with me.  I am trying again to understand....honestly, this discussion makes me feel dumb as a rock! OK, so the gerund clause functions as a noun clause.  The gerund itself is the verb in the gerund clause, so it is NOT a noun, but the verb portion of a noun clause.  Is that correct?

Comment: I also looked at your complements handout.  You state that there are four kinds of complements--infinitive, gerund, that clause and embedded question.  I'm trying to mesh this with what I know of complements---subject complements (adjectives and nouns that rename or re-describe the subject "Susan is a homemaker.  Susan is industrious."---and object complement nouns and adjectives:  "He called me brother.  He called me lazy."  My definition of complement may indeed be muddy.  I'm thinking that a complement completes or fills out a our understanding of a noun?

Comment: Also, I am intrigued by your sentence:  "Grammar is about constituents, like clauses and phrases, rather than about words."  I think this is the key to me making sense of the "my" in my other question as well as the key to my understanding of this gerund issue. I think you are saying that it's about groups of words and how they group together...not the individual words.

Comment: I am also grappling with the idea of non-infinite clauses (infinitives and gerunds) as I think of a clause: "A clause is a group of words that contains both a subject and a verb."  You mention that they "often do not have overt subjects" because they may be "indefinite or under identity."   So do gerunds and infinitive clauses have implied subjects?

Comment: Finally, I think I understand POSS-ing is possessive form, but I am not sure what ACC-ing refers to?  The term "matrix predicate" completely blows my mind...reading that over and over but still can't understand it.

Comment: That's more questions than I can answer this way, Elizabeth. Don't be concerned about terminology; it's just names. The matrix predicate is the main verb (or predicate adjective or predicate noun, etc) of a clause. Yes, untensed clauses frequently have missing subjects: _Playing the tuba at 3am is not popular_. What is the subject of _Playing_? `Indefinite`.

Comment: Yes, I see your point about the missing subject in the example above.  Bear with me for two more questions, then I will stop.  1) In my sentence above "Good writing requires hard work," would you say writing is a "true noun" or "a verbal noun" (#5 in your original link) but not a gerund?   2) What book/site do you recommend I consult to straighten out all these grammar questions I'm generating?  Thank you again!

Comment: It's hard to tell in a specific instance; changing the sentence by tests may cause it to mean something else than what was intended. But I would say it's a "true noun"; I used "verbal noun" only to indicate that it derives from a verb, and has the same shape as a verb form, like adjectives formed from participles (e.g, _shelled_ in _soft shelled crabs_, which is clearly not a participle because there's no English verb _shell_ meaning 'have a shell'). As for books, [McCawley 1998](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/S/bo3613599.html) is where this is laid out most clearly.