# In “can hear singing”, is “singing” a verb or a gerund?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sense-verbs, gerund-phrases, grammatical-roles, participial-phrases

In this sentence is *singing* a verb or a gerund?

> Look at the children whom you can hear singing.

Comment: You can ask the same question with a simpler sentence, like *I hear the children singing* or *I heard them singing.* It becomes more interesting when you contrast ***singing children*** with ***children singing*** though, like comparing *Singing children are a delight to the ear and eye* versus *I don’t like to hear monarchist children singing that anti-democratic doggerel on Independence Day of all days.*

Comment: [All gerunds are verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/154790).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a gerund be modified by an adjective?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154772/can-a-gerund-be-modified-by-an-adjective)

Answer (score 3):

*Singing* is a *present participle* in the case (following @tchrist ’s suggestion) of “I hear children singing.”

It would be a gerund, i.e., serving in lieu of a noun as direct object of verb *hear,* if you got rid of the children: “I hear singing.” But in “I hear children singing,” the direct object of the verb is *children,* and *singing* is an adjectival modifier thereof, a common function for participles.

A partially analogous construction is available using the past participle, as in “I heard the aria sung,” though the use of the past participle makes the construction passive where the present makes it active: the child *sings,* the aria *is sung.*

Comment: Of course, it is still a verb there, since the nonfinite clause *children singing songs* has a direct object (*songs*) and even a subject, too (*children*).  The whole clause is the direct object of *hear*.

Comment: No, the direct object of _hear_ in _I hear (the) children singing_ is the gerund clause _(the) children singing_. Try a cleft on it: _(The )Children singing is what I hear_; or passivize it: _Children singing (sweetly) was heard by everyone in the room_.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think this confusion arises out of thinking that a direct object must be a single substantive rather than a constituent.

Comment: Now **that's** an interesting question.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, I know. That's what the third grade teacher said, and who studies grammar after grammar school?

Comment: @JohnLawler, I think your clefts both warrant asterisks: children singing *are* what I hear / *were* heard by all (though perhaps the *children's* singing *was* heard by all. (I realize Prof. Pullum will probably slam his door on me for daring to use possessive with gerund, but hey, maybe it has a valid disambiguating function!) And the direct object *may* be a single substantive, surely?

Comment: Both possessive and accusative gerund complementizers are perfectly normal. There's another sense of _children singing_ that means the same but has a different construction; from _children (who are) singing_, and that's plural. But if you add _sweetly_ to the gerund, you get _(The )Children singing sweetly is what I hear_, and that's unquestionably sentential and singular. "Children singing" by itself is ambiguous between modified plural noun and singular clause; but one can prefer one interpretation, especially in a context where it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In comments, John Lawler wrote:

> The direct object of *hear* in *I hear (the) children singing* is the gerund clause *(the) children singing*.
>
> - Try a cleft on it: *(The )Children singing is what I hear*;
> - or passivize it: *Children singing (sweetly) was heard by everyone in the room*.
>
> Both possessive and accusative gerund complementizers are perfectly normal. There's another sense of *children singing* that means the same but has a different construction; from *children (who are) singing*, and that's plural. But if you add *sweetly* to the gerund, you get *(The )Children singing sweetly is what I hear*, and that's unquestionably sentential and singular.
>
> "Children singing" by itself is ambiguous between modified plural noun and singular clause; but one can prefer one interpretation, especially in a context where it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It might be just me, but 'Children singing (sweetly) was heard by everyone in the room' sounds off to my ears. But 'Children singing sweetly was what I heard' sounds quite acceptable.