# Gerund: Difference between “knowledge” and “knowing”

Tags: nouns, gerunds

In these days I find out something about The Gerunds and now i want to know what's The difference between these nouns “knowledge” and “knowing”? And which one on is Gerund?

Clearing: in my language or French language your Gerund become the Name of infinitive for example The name of infinitive of "To know" is "Knowledge" and when I search for translate of "Knowing" Translate the same thing of Infinitive, I want to know which one of them is Gerund? Knowledge or Knowing, if knowledge is Gerund what is Knowing?

Thank you.

Comment: What research have you done yourself?

Comment: @TimLymington A lot of research, but without any result because my teacher isn't good and can't help me and every one in the Internet say something different and can't say something useful! so i try to reach into a full answer with this question.

Comment: 'Knowledge' is often used for a major subject area: knowledge of French, scientific knowledge. It's also preferred for constructions like 'Her knowledge of the tables has improved'. Here, 'Knowing the tables is important' could also be used. 'Knowing' ('Knowing how to drive a car is vital', 'Knowing you is such fun' ... tends to be used to cover more specialised and especially practical and interpersonal relationship situations.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, it is true, this is the using of these but the thing i am looking for is that in my language or French language your Gerund become the Name of infinitive for example The name of infinitive of "To know" is "Knowledge" and when i search for translate of "Knowing" Translate the same thing of Infinitive, I want to know what's Gerund? Knowledge or Knowing, if knowledge is Gerund what is Knowing? I hope my letter is clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at some of John Lawler's [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/154790/16980), which I have found enlightening.

** Could this be changed to a comment? My mistake.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. According to John Lawler's answer, I have a question, Now what's the difference between Infinitive and Gerund?

Comment: Gerunds use _-ing_ complementizer, while infinitives use _for...to_.

Answer (score -1):

For example, someone can - *look knowing* - as in, they look like they *already know* something. Someone cannot *look knowledge* - but someone can *have knowledge* - hope this makes sense... E.g.

> John gave a knowing smile (because he had knowledge of...)

Comment: Irrelevant. This is an adjectival use of _knowing_, derived from the participle. The question is about the nominal us of _knowing_, and the choice between it and the derived noun _knowledge_. -1.